# How to rename files in folders, replacing beginning of file name with parent foldername

Tags: powershell

I have almost 2000 folders named after different product names like `G00114`.
The files in these folders should be prefixed with the product name but some of them have been named incorrectly like so `00114_300_f_resized_65.jpg`.

Therefore I need to replace alle characters before the `_` with the parent folder name.

This is what I imagine I need but I don't know if there is any such command that will allow me to replace "characters before the `_`" and if the code is written correctly

```
get-childitem -recurse *jpg |
  foreach {
    rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("characters before the "_"", ".Directory.Name")
  }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regex replace:

```
$_.Name -replace '.*(?=_)', $_.Directory.Name
```

Or, if you want to replace the characters only up to the first `_`:

```
$_.Name -replace '.*?(?=_)', $_.Directory.Name
```

Comment: Thank Joey very much for you answer. I can't get it to work. I apologize I am not well versed in the arts of powershell command.

This is the line i type:

get-childitem -recurse *jpg | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name -replace '.*?(?=_)', $_.Directory.Name }

I get this error:

Rename-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'replace'.
At line:1 char:64

Answer (score 0):

```
gci 'c:\temp\*.jpg' -Recurse |  %{ Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.Name -replace $_.Name.split('_')[0], $_.Directory.Name ) -Verbose}
```